# Installing CUDA 10.2 and Ubuntu standard Nvidia driver

Tags: 18.04, cuda, gpu-driver

When trying to install CUDA 10.2, I get the following message:

> Existing package manager installation of the driver found. It is strongly recommended that you remove this before continuing.

In CUDA installation guides for Ubuntu I haven't seen the recommendation to remove the current Nvidia drivers before continuing with CUDA installation. So should I remove them or not?

Comment: The existing package manager will update Nvidia driver modules for each kernel update. You will have to do that yourself if you use any other driver source, That said, if a driver version beyond what is offered by the standard repos or graphics-drivers repo, is required by 10.2, that is what you will have to do until that version is available in graphics-drivers (then the standard repos). What version do you need?

Comment: @ubfan1 I decided to just install the current repo version of nvidia-cuda-toolkit. I think it's 9.x, but I don't care that much.